# my code didnt break and try to fill every line

Tags: html, css, pymongo

i try to launch my code to crete a simple elearning website which use pymongo as database. i write the codes in google docs before it save it in pymongo.

the main problem is, my code didnt break(br) like it use to and even trying to fill all line. this only occur to short code but doesnt do the same with long one. it happen sometimes but i cant seems to get it fix. i did try to remove the css to see if the problem is from there but same thing happens. i dont know what seems to be the problem.

```
<h4>i love food</h4>

<p>there are many food i like.</p>

<p>the food are as follow:</p>
<ul>
    <li>chicken</li>
    <li>fish</li>
    <li>nugget</li>
    </ul><br>

<p>all from above is my favourite</p>

<h4>MA 7 & EMA 26</h4><br>
```

here are a simple code similar to mine. but the problem is the code stacks.

result :

```
i love food  

there are many food like.
the food are as follow:  .chicken     all from above is my favourite
                            .fish
                            .nugget

MA 7 & EMA 26
```

as you can see, some stack and some dont. im preatty sure is not the code. but  cant think of another problem.

Comment: Your first two words are "my code". So where is said code?

Comment: the problem happens at many places and i cant post image to clear my problem. the code is stacking trying to fill next to each other. even break cant separate them. but some code from other page are fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine !

https://jsfiddle.net/zvdqk0mr/

Use `<div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>` and CSS `.clear{clear:both;}`

instead of `<br>` if you facing this line break issue

https://jsfiddle.net/zvdqk0mr/1/